# "Dream of" vs. "dream about"

Tags: differences, phrasal-verbs

What is the difference between the usage of *dream of* and *dream about*? For example,

> I dream of becoming a doctor.
> I dream about becoming a doctor.
>
> I dream of going to places.
> I dream about going to places.

If I mean *dream* as in dreaming while I am asleep, then which is preferable?

Comment: I think any supposed distinction is purely subjective. According to [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+dream+of%2CI+dream+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20dream%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20dream%20about%3B%2Cc0), ***of*** has been around longer, and is still 2-3 times more common. But they're both perfectly valid in literal *and* figurative contexts, and effectively interchangeable to most (but doubtless not *all* native speakers).

Comment: (1) What @FumbleFingers said. (2) Look up *of* and *about* in the dictionary.

Answer (score 12):

'I dream of' is usually talking about your goals/aspirations. So

> I dream of becoming a doctor

means

> I want to become a doctor some day

and 'I dream about' usually talks about your actual dreams. So

> I dream about becoming a doctor

means

> I have actual dreams in which I become a doctor.

Answer (score 1):

'I dream of' is usually followed by a verb:

> I dream of winning the World Cup

'I dream about' is usually used when referring to a noun:

> I dream about chocolate ice cream

However, I have seen these used interchangeably.

Comment: It sounds like a logical theory, but comparing Google Books citations for [I dream of having](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+dream+of+having%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) and [I dream about having](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+dream+about+having%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (which return similar counts), I see no real evidence to suggest people actually make any such distinction.

Comment: ... a pipe dream?

Comment: A famous american TV sitcom in the sixties was called _"I Dream of Jeannie"_. That's an example of usage of _dream of_ refering to a person/noun.

Comment: Titles and lyrics aren't conclusive but Madonna famously sang "Last night I dreamt of San Pedro".

Answer (score 0):

for me who is far away from native speaker )) this explanation is 100% clear:

> "We use "dream about" for actual dreams that we have when we're
> asleep, and "dream of" for ambitions.
>
> - I dreamt about my old schoolfriends last night.
> - I dream of having my own little house by the sea."

(credits go to the La Liseuse user and this explanation was taken from there: https://www.italki.com/en/post/question-427581 )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, you should mention and link to (if online) the source where you got this from. Also, the parts that you copied should be quoted, which you can do with `>` at the start of each line.

Comment: Thanks for adding the source; can you also reformat it?

Comment: @Heartspring re-format how? please, clarify

Comment: What Laurel said, adding blockquotes (>) to offset the quoted parts.